# Jenkins - список переменных окружения

Tags: jenkins

Есть jenkinks в котором прогеры билдят свои проекты. Есть задача, при успешном билде какого либо продукта скачивать его.

Создал свою сборку, которая отслеживает сборки коллег, указал что при стабильной сборке запускать скрипт, скрипт на powershell, которые дергает api и скачивает сборку, и работает отлично, если ссылку я в скрипте жестко задаю, а хотелось бы получить имя отслеживаемого проета: увидел, что над скриптом есть ссылка на список переменных окружения, но проблема в том, что этот список содержит данные моей сборки, а мне нужно получить имя сборки которую он отследил, как бы такое реализовать и реализуемо ли это вообще?